# Can't update variable inside CMake marcro

Tags: macros, cmake

How can I modify a parameter inside a CMake Macro?

I'm using CMake version 2.6 and I can't update the variable!

Here's a basic example:

```
# macro definition
MACRO(MYTEST RETVAL)
message("input RETVAL=${RETVAL}")
SET(RETVAL "new return value")
message("after update RETVAL=${RETVAL}")
ENDMACRO(MYTEST)

# call macro with parameter '_test' set to 'init'
SET(_test "init")
MYTEST("${_test}")
message("after macro call:${_test}")
```

This prints:

```
input RETVAL=init
after update RETVAL=init
after macro call:init
```

The variable `_test` is never modified. What can I do to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With CMake macros, you need to *very carefully* distinguish between macro parameter name, variable name, variable value etc. It's not quite clear from your CMake code what you want to achieve, but I assume you want to set `_test` to the string `new return value` using the macro.

This is the code to accomplish that:

```
macro(MYTEST RETVAL)
  message("input variable name: RETVAL=${RETVAL}")
  message("input variable value: ${${RETVAL}}")
  set(${RETVAL} "new return value")
  message("variable name after update: RETVAL=${RETVAL}")
  message("variable value after update: ${${RETVAL}}")
endmacro()

set(_test "init")
MYTEST(_test)
message("after macro call: ${_test}")
```

Points to note:

- You want the macro to modify the variable which was passed in. That variable's name is stored in the macro parameter `RETVAL`. So you need to `set(${RETVAL} ...)` to set the varibale. Your code was creating a variable named `RETVAL`.
- You need to pass the *name* of the variable to change to the macro. So you must pass `_test`, and not `${_test}`. Your code was calling the macro with the text `init`.